# How Telegram android app Shows multiple layouts just in a ViewGroup with "No Boundaries"?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, telegram, android-viewgroup

I set the "show layout boundaries" on Developer options of my phone and i see the layout for each row of RecyclerView(or ListView?) in Telegram app is just one ViewGroup. As you see each row has just one element and the child views don't have any boundaries.

[image]

How is that possible keeping in mind that in each row we have ImageView and textView or maybe other elements, but what we see is just one ViewGroup containing all the views but it seems that each View doesn't have any boundaries?

if you create a recyclerView, each row will appear as below(Every child view will has its own boundaries):

[image]

Note:

I guess that maybe they use `<merge>` tag there. But i am not sure.

Comment: That's a simply RelativeLayout with a ListView(RecyclerView) and a LinearLayout (for the message and the emoticons)

Comment: @LucaNicoletti   I added another picture with my implementation. as you see in my case there is boundaries for each child view in a row but in the telegram just the viewGroup has boundaries. How is that possible?

Comment: That's because each element in RecyclerView has just 2 childs: the text box, and the other small one on the right corner

Comment: Interested!!!! if you found it outmake me aware too. thanks